# Why are my two divs always next to each other?

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

I'm trying to use d3json create some tables, I would also like to insert some content between tables. However, these tables always stick together, and the content that I intend to insert between them, would appear in unexpected place.

[image]

The website turns out to look like this. Ideally the word "space" should appear between the two tables. I tried the same thing in w3school, substituting the two tables with some static data, and it was good. I guess the issue is with the script then? But how can that affect the appearance given the fact that they are in different divs? Thanks a lot.

```js
d3.json('data.json', function (error,data) {

      function tabulate(data, columns) {
        var table = d3.select(sector).append('table')
        var thead = table.append('thead')
        var tbody = table.append('tbody');

        // append the header row
        thead.append('tr')
          .selectAll('th')
          .data(columns).enter()
          .append('th')
            .text(function (column) { return column; });

        // create a row for each object in the data
        var rows = tbody.selectAll('tr')
          .data(data)
          .enter()
          .append('tr');

        // create a cell in each row for each column
        var cells = rows.selectAll('td')
          .data(function (row) {
            return columns.map(function (column) {
              return {column: column, value: row[column]};
            });
          })
          .enter()
          .append('td')
            .text(function (d) { return d.value; });

        return table;
      }

      // render the table(s)
      tabulate(data, ['date', 'close']); // 2 column table

    });
```

```css
.bar_graph{
    font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #000;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.bar {
    fill: steelblue;

}

.x.axis path {
    display: none;
}

#table1 table,#table2 table{
    font-family: arial,16px sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 70%;
}
td, th {

  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}
tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <html>
      <head>
        <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'>
      </head>
      <body>
        <!--First Table-->
        <div id="table1">
          <script>
            var sector = "#table1"
          </script>
          <script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
        </div>
      <!--Space header-->
      <h1> space </h1>
      <!--Second Table-->
      <div id="table2">
        <script>
          var sector = "#table2"
        </script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
      </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use style="margin-top:10px;" for  tag.
You may change the top margin as required. This should be applied in second table.